# How to drag and drop an element for xcode-ui-testing in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, xcode9, ios-ui-automation, swift3.2

UI Test for an ios-app, developed in Xcode 8 and swift 3.2.

I'm facing a problem to deal with drag and drop after upgrading Xcode version 8 to 9

I would like to drag an element `[i.e. button]` and drop it to another element `[i.e. on homepage]`.

For Xcode 8, I implemented it using below method:

```
let sourceElement = app.buttons["Video_Button"]

let destElement = app.scrollViews.scrollViews.images.element(boundBy: 0)

sourceElement.press(forDuration: 0.5, thenDragTo: destElement)
```

But the above code is not working in Xcode 9 and Swift 3.2.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how is it not working? What happens when you run test?

Comment: When executing the line `sourceElement.press(forDuration: 0.5, thenDragTo: destElement)` it returns failure and exiting the system.

Comment: It happens only in Xcode 9

Comment: What failure? Please post logs here.

Comment: Log is a bit long. Please come on chat or send me your email address.

Comment: You can always edit your question and post log here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161297/discussion-between-ali-azam-and-lagoman).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually issue is in iOS 11.0.

In iOS 11.0 some hierarchical elements failed to **tap** or **press** or **longpress**.

You have to work with the elements center point to do the **tap** or **press** or **longpress**.

**  **Code snippet** for the **Solution** of the problem is pasted below.

First create an extension method for press on a center of the element and drag this element to the destination elements center.

**Extension method is below**

```
extension XCUIElement {

func dragAndDropUsingCenterPos(forDuration duration: TimeInterval,
                               thenDragTo destElement: XCUIElement) {

    let sourceCoordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5))

    let destCorodinate: XCUICoordinate = destElement.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5))

    sourceCoordinate.press(forDuration: duration, thenDragTo: destCorodinate)
  }

}
```

**Then call the extension method like below**

```
 sourceElement.dragAndDropUsingCenterPos(forDuration: 0.5, thenDragTo: destElement)
```

Hope it will solve your issue. Let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thanks Mahmud and appreciated, It works like a charm.